# How to get all friends name, id, birthday, location, etc.. from facebook API in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, date

I want to display the list that contain information like name, id, birthday, location from facebook in iPhone application.

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,birthday,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil]];
```

but i am not getting birthday using this.Please give me some guideline to achieve this task.